# Как в C++ вывести число в экспоненциальной форме с "E" а не "e"?

Tags: c++

Допустим программа что то считает и выводит результат: 7.4e+016
Как сделать так, чтобы программа вывела вот такую запись: 7.4E+016
То есть чтобы выводилась не маленькая буква "e", а большая буква "E"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужны [`std::uppercase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/uppercase/) и  [`std::scientific`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/scientific/)

```
std::cout << std::uppercase << std::scientific << 3.1415926;
```

Выводит

```
3.141593E+00
```

[Пример](http://cpp.sh/4kake)